# QListWidget Item different color for highlighted items

Tags: python, qlistwidget, pyside2

I have a QListWidget in PySide2 and I would like different colors for the selected items. Is this possible? I will include 2 pictures to demonstrate.

What I have currently:
[image]

And this is what I would like to have:

[image]

Comment: I am using PySide2 and it is a QListWidget.  I want two kinds of highlight colors, one would be the standard highlight blue color for a QListWidget, and the other would be a darker shade of blue for other highlighted items in the widget. I will work on an example to post.

Comment: I recommend that for next questions signals that you are using PySide2, not every solution for PySide is compatible for PySide2, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a delegate and override the QPalette of the QStyleOptionViewItem. In the following example, the highlight color depends on whether it is an even row or not.

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random


class HighlightedDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(HighlightedDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        # highlight color
        color = (
            QtGui.QColor("gray")
            if index.row() % 2 == 0
            else QtGui.QColor("salmon")
        )
        option.palette.setColor(
            QtGui.QPalette.Normal, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, color
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QListWidget(
        selectionMode=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection
    )
    delegate = HighlightedDelegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    for i in range(100):
        it = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem("item-{}".format(i))
        w.addItem(it)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]